# Is Moodle PENS Compliant?

Tags: moodle

I have been trying to find the answer to this but it doesn't seem to be anywhere.  Does anyone know if Moodle is PENS compliant?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Moodle is not Package Exchange Notification Services (PENS) compliant.

The specification does not appear to be [too hairy](http://www.aicc.org/docs/tech/cmi010v1a.pdf), but i have not found any indication that anyone has tried to implement it for Moodle.

Some alternatives you could consider:

- A 3rd party content, such as [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/) (commercial service)
- *Learning Tools Interoperability* (LTI), which is a set of protocols which appear to be similar to PENS, i.e. you designate your LMS as a provider or consumer, and content can be shared. Moodle has consumer support built in. Acting as a provider can be achieved [using a plugin](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/LTI_Provider).